# Taanit dibbur breaking

Tags: halacha, fast-days, nedarim-shevuot, speech-talking

If one vows to do Taanit dibbur, when are they allowed to violate it? Could they violate it in cases of substantial financial or reputational harm? Are there any sources for this?

Comment: I would assume one can do hataras nedarim, where a beis din (3 men) try to deduce if you didn't forsee your current circumstances when you made the neder, and if you didn't, they'll say that your neder was invalid.

Comment: @Kovy How on earth will you do hataras nedarim without speaking?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi Writing, nodding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav Chaim Kanievsky (Shoneh Halachos, Moadim, 572:10, page 217, note 2) is quoted as ruling that one need only refrain from “idle words.” However, if one must speak to perform a chesed or other important matters, he may speak. Furthermore, he concludes that if one’s wife requires some conversation, this, too, is not forbidden.
https://yated.com/taanis-dibbur-fast-whose-time-come/